# Using bind to ensure method refers to object, but it doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, oop, methods, bind

Furthering my experiments in proper Javascript, I'm trying to run one method (SayHello) from another (WaitAndSayHello). As a callback is involved, I have used [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to ensure that 'this' in each method refers to the object.

```
pretendThingConstructor = function (greeting) {
    this.greeting = greeting;

    this.SayHello = function() {
        console.log(this.greeting); // Works
    };

    this.WaitAndSayHello = function() {
        setTimeout(function() { 
            console.log(this)  
            this.SayHello() // Fails
        }, 500);
    }
    this.WaitAndSayHello.bind(this); // This bind() doesn't seem to work
}


var pretend_thing = new pretendThingConstructor('hello world');
pretend_thing.SayHello();
pretend_thing.WaitAndSayHello();
```

The code prints 'hello world', then fails with 'Object # has no method 'SayHello'' the second time around. I can see, from the console.log, that 'this' is referring to the event. However shouldn't have using bind() fixed this?

How can I make the bind() work?

Additionally, I'd like to do this cleanly: ie, without referring to the name of the object in multiple places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't "late call" `.bind()`. You need to invoke it at function declaration time, like

```
this.WaitAndSayHello = function() {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        console.log(this)  
        this.SayHello() // Fails
    }, 500);
}.bind(this)
```

Furthermore, the anonymous function you pass into `setTimeout()` creates a new context and therefore, has its own `this` context value.

You either need to hold a reference to the "outer `this`" in a variable like

```
this.WaitAndSayHello = function() {
    var self = this;

    setTimeout(function() { 
        console.log(self)  
        self.SayHello() // succeeds
    }, 500);
}.bind(this)
```

or use `.bind()` again, like

```
this.WaitAndSayHello = function() {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        console.log(this)  
        this.SayHello() // succeeds
    }.bind(this), 500);
}.bind(this)
```

Comment: Thanks @jAndy, that explains things perfectly. I've always found something about 'var self = this' a bit hacky, so I've using the second solution - I suspect it will become part of my day-to-day JS programming, so thanks again.

Comment: @nailer: very welcome. Remember, `.bind()` is part of ES5 so it might not natively available in old'ish browser. But its very easy to shim and there are lots of shims available out there.

Comment: PS. @jAndy I think we can get away with only one bind - on the function called from setTimeout. binding WaitAndSayHello is unnecessary. You may wish to update your answer for the next guy.

Answer (score 1):

you should use:

```
this.WaitAndSayHello.call(this);
```

or

```
this.WaitAndSayHello.apply(this);
```

the difference between `apply` and `call` is the way you would pass arguments to the called function: imagine `WaitAndSayHello` received some args:

```
this.WaitAndSayHello = function(toWho, helloMessage){
 ...
}
```

with `call`, you would pass the arguments after the context, as you were invoking the function normally:

```
this.WaitAndSayHello.call(this, 'Bob', 'Hello');
```

with `apply`, you would have to pass the args as an array:

```
this.WaitAndSayHello.apply(this, ['Bob', 'Hello']);
```

## Edit

Sorry, i read your code wrong, @jAndy's anwser is really the right one, however, to use my logic you could do something like:

```
this.WaitAndSayHello = function() {
        setTimeout.call(this, function() { 
            console.log(this)  
            this.SayHello() // Fails
        }, 500);
    }
```

Comment: How would this change the `this` referencing to DOM window within the `setTimeout` callback?